# Boundary Conditions for a system of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems, characteristics

Given a system of following PDEs:

$$
u_{x} + v_{y} + 3u-v=0
\\
u_{y} - w_{x}+uw=0
\\
v_{x}-w_{y}=0
$$

I found that the given system of equations is of mixed elliptic-hyperbolic type with the characteristics as $1, \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}$
The goal is to find where initial conditions and boundary conditions should be prescribed on a rectangular domain.

Now the solution given to me is as shown here

[Solution of Boundary Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Sfi.png)

Can someone please help me in understanding **how** we arrived at this solution?

Comment: When the dimension of the problem, what is the dimension of the domain, and what are the derivative orders?

Comment: It's a 2D problem. All the derivatives are of 1st order

Comment: Alright, then from that you should be able to say what IC/BC you would need.

Comment: In the solution they've prescribed boundary conditions for $v$ and $w$ on all boundaries and initial condition for $u$. How was this decided? Why not an initial condition on $v$ and boundary condition in $v$ and $w$?

Comment: This depends on the problem and we do not have much context here.